# "В(,) казалось бы". Можно ли ставить запятую после предлога?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

> Лишь через три с лишним минуты, когда он уже начал задыхаться, то заметил брешь в *казалось бы* безупречных движениях гладиатора.

Помогите, пожалуйста, с запятыми. Выделять ли вводное «казалось бы»? Или лучше переформулировать, чтобы вводное не отделяло предлог от существительного?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Можно ли ставить запятую после предлога?

Можно. Вот что писали по этому поводу Былинский с Розенталем (*"Трудные случаи пунктуации"*, М., 1959):

> Если вводное слово находится между предлогом и существительным, то оно
>   по общему правилу выделяется запятыми, например: *Радость его подобна
>   радости врача, вдохнувшего жизнь в, **казалось бы**, остановившееся сердце
>   больного.*

Но (!) далее:

> Однако следует избегать такого рода построений предложения, т. е. не
>   отрывать предлога от управляемого существительного (*Радость его
>   подобна радости врача, вдохнувшего жизнь в остановившееся, **казалось
>   бы**, сердце больного*).

Ваше предложение лучше переформулировать. Но перенос вводного ***казалось бы*** недостаточен. Попробуйте выкинуть придаточное и посмотрите, что у Вас получится:

*Лишь через три с лишним минуты <…> **то** заметил брешь…*

Как вариант:

***Лишь через три с лишним минуты, начав уже задыхаться, заметил он брешь в безупречных, казалось бы,  движениях гладиатора.***

Answer (score 1):

Если стоит задача внести минимум исправлений, то предлагаю вариант, в который включены только абсолютно необходимые исправления:

*Лишь через три с лишним минуты, когда уже начал задыхаться, он заметил брешь в, казалось бы, безупречных движениях гладиатора.*